# Oracle12 outer join invents column values

Tags: left-join, outer-join, oracle12c

If I execute the following statements on an Oracle12 db I get a result I simply cannot explain:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    a_id NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( a_id )
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    b_id NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    col_1 NUMBER ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( b_id )
);

ALTER TABLE table_b
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES table_a (a_id);

insert into table_a (a_id) values (1);
insert into table_a (a_id) values (2);
insert into table_a (a_id) values (3);
insert into table_a (a_id) values (4);
insert into table_b (b_id, col_1) values (1, 100);
insert into table_b (b_id, col_1) values (2, 101);

select a_id, b_id, col_1
    from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4);
```

This results in the following output:

```
      A_ID       B_ID      COL_1
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         3          3
         4          4
```

To my understanding, the values 3 and 4 in column `B_ID` should not be there, because the table only contains values 1 and 2:

```
select * from table_b;

      B_ID      COL_1
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        101
```

And to list the complete data, here is `table_a`:

```
select * from table_a;

      A_ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
```

Here is some more information on the execution path:

```
select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, '+OUTLINE' ) );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------
SQL_ID  6wg8b65y25utv, child number 2
-------------------------------------
select a_id, b_id, col_1     from table_a left outer join table_b on
a_id=b_id     where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4)

Plan hash value: 2951123891

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |              |     1 |    39 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INLIST ITERATOR            |              |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0013651 |     3 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_B      |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0013653 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 11)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_caching' 90)
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$948754D7")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      INDEX(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" ("TABLE_A"."A_ID"))
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1" ("TABLE_B"."B_ID"))
      LEADING(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access(("TABLE_A"."A_ID"=1 OR "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=3 OR "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=4))
   5 - access("A_ID"="B_ID")
       filter(("B_ID"=1 OR "B_ID"=3 OR "B_ID"=4))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=AUTO)
   - statistics feedback used for this statement
   - this is an adaptive plan


58 rows selected.
```

What I found out so far is that the result is correct, if

- the statements from above are executed on a lower Oracle version
- I do not query `col_1`
- the where clause is ommitted
- `and (b_id is null or b_id=1)` is added to the where clause
- I drop the primary key from `table_b`

Without `col_1` there is the following execution plan information (which produces the correct result):

```
SQL> select a_id, b_id
    from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4);

      A_ID       B_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         3
         4

SQL> select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, '+OUTLINE' ) );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------
SQL_ID  cnycu7vr2k975, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select a_id, b_id     from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4)

Plan hash value: 2928418244

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |              |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER |              |     3 |    78 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INLIST ITERATOR   |              |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| SYS_C0013651 |     3 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN | SYS_C0013653 |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 11)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_caching' 90)
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$948754D7")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      INDEX(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" ("TABLE_A"."A_ID"))
      INDEX(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1" ("TABLE_B"."B_ID"))
      LEADING(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access(("TABLE_A"."A_ID"=1 OR "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=3 OR
              "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=4))
   4 - access("A_ID"="B_ID")
       filter(("B_ID"=1 OR "B_ID"=3 OR "B_ID"=4))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=AUTO)
```

Without the primary key constraint but including `col_1`, there is the following execution plan information (which also produces the correct result):

```
SQL> alter table table_b drop primary key;

Table altered.

SQL> select a_id, b_id, col_1
    from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4);

      A_ID       B_ID      COL_1
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         3
         4

SQL> select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, '+OUTLINE' ) );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------
SQL_ID  6wg8b65y25utv, child number 2
-------------------------------------
select a_id, b_id, col_1     from table_a left outer join table_b on
a_id=b_id     where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4)

Plan hash value: 3493943395

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |              |       |       |     4 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER    |              |     3 |   117 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INLIST ITERATOR   |              |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| SYS_C0013651 |     3 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | TABLE_B      |     1 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 11)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20)
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_caching' 90)
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$948754D7")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$8812AA4E")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      INDEX(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" ("TABLE_A"."A_ID"))
      FULL(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      LEADING(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$1" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      USE_HASH(@"SEL$2BFA4EE4" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$1")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A_ID"="B_ID")
   3 - access(("TABLE_A"."A_ID"=1 OR "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=3 OR
              "TABLE_A"."A_ID"=4))
   4 - filter(("B_ID"=1 OR "B_ID"=3 OR "B_ID"=4))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=AUTO)


56 rows selected.
```

I have the strong feeling that Oracles optimizer is somehow so badly misconfigured that the query result is wrong. But unfortunately I have no direct access to it.

**Question: Is the result of the select query from above correct? And if not, what optimizer settings do I need to change to get the correct result?**

Comment: post a script where you first show that the tables are indeed empty before you insert those values.  something isn't right about what you're explaining/seeing.

Comment: The output occurs if I execute all statements I included in my question: starting with an empty database and creating fresh tables.

Comment: I thought including a transcript of selecting and showing 0 rows would help, and it still might.  But without an available Oracle sandbox to reproduce myself, I don't have a clue why this would happen - sorry!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I copy all statements I included in my question and paste them into a sqlplus session, I receive the shown output. But I cannot explain it - it seems to be wrong. Does anyone get the same result? Can anyone point me to some optimizer settings that may cause such behavior?

Comment: To me it is a bid odd to have a non-composite Primary key on table_B that is also a foreign key to a. .  If table_B had a different field for PK vs FK does the problem persist? Otherwise your join between the tables is an optional 1-to-1 relationship; in which case why have table B at all?  That being said, It should work and not provide B_ID values.  As you stated, earlier versions produce the expected results: Version 11.2.0.4.0 did.  Might be a good Ask Tom question!

Comment: @xQbert: The example in my question is greatly simplified: The original table structure is generated by Hibernate where table_a contains all attributes of a (base) DNS resource record and table_b (as well as many other child tables I omitted for simplicity) represent the concrete resource record types. So it is indeed an optional 1:1 relationship. If I split up PK and FK, I guess the correct result would be returned (because it is, if I remove the PK). Perhaps you are right and I should "Ask Tom". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the following results:

```
      A_ID       B_ID      COL_1
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         3
         4
```

... which I think is the correct answer.

Can you run you query, and then immediately after, run the following, and post the output:

```
select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, '+OUTLINE' ) );
```

Comment: Hi BobC, this is the result I also would have expected. I updated my question to contain the information you requested.

Comment: @OlafZiems. This is quite strange. The plan looks correct. You have a few optimizer parameters set (which is an argument for another day; I don't think they are affecting your output). Are you running on an old or beta version of 12.1.0.2?  You also said that not querying col1 gives the correct result. Can you post that, together with the execution plan?

Comment: I added more execution plans to the question. Removing the primary key constraint also fixes the output. Adding a unique constraint instead of the primary key also produces the correct result. My Oracle version is: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning option

Comment: @OlafZiems. Lets rule out the optimizer parameters. Can you try resetting the two optimizer_index_xxx parameters to their default.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head :). Adding /*+ OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 100) */ after "select" (where 100 is the default value) returns the correct result. Great help!

Comment: @OlafZiems. Ok, thats a bug. Let me see if it's a known one; otherwise I'll file a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Can you post a link to the bug here, so we can track it?

Answer (score 0):

To sum things up, I post this answer to my own problem, that could solve it for me.

If I create the tables and insert the data as shown in my question, then the following produces the wrong result (I added the optimizer parameter to make my current global setting more clear. The same output is returned if I omit the hint):

```
SQL> select /*+ OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20) */ a_id, b_id, col_1
    from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4);

      A_ID       B_ID      COL_1
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         3          3
         4          4
```

Whereas if I change the value of the optimizer parameter `optimizer_index_cost_adj` from 20 (currently globally configured on my Oracle) to 100 (the default value), the correct result shows up:

```
SQL> select /*+ OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 100) */ a_id, b_id, col_1
    from table_a left outer join table_b on a_id=b_id
    where a_id in (1 , 3 , 4);

      A_ID       B_ID      COL_1
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         3
         4
```

The only thing that still puzzles me is, that nobody out there is able reproduce the issue. So there seems to be something more to it...